# Remove first line of json file before getting data with Dio

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I have a json file that I'm getting from the web that starts with the characters `)]}',`. Example:

```
)]}',
{<DATA START HERE>}
```

I want to read this data with `Response response = await dio.get(url);`, but the first line of that json file is causing errors. How can I tell dio to skip the first line?

Comment: Simple - thats not JSON.

Comment: Here's the example url that I'm trying to read from: https://25live.collegenet.com/25live/data/umd/run/availability/availabilitydata.json?obj_cache_accl=0&start_dt=2019-05-2T00:00:00&compview=null&comptype=availability&compsubject=location&page_size=100&spaces_name=pls&spaces_category_id=8&include=closed+blackouts+pending+related+empty&caller=pro-AvailDao.getData

Comment: Again that simply broken response. Nothing you can do about it. To read such crap, you will have to fetch data as TEXT and process it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's rather strange. I wonder if it's some special guard characters generated by the server. Ask them why they add it.

That said, as long as it's the same pattern each time, it looks like the garbage is on a different line from the json. So, just split the string and pick up the second line.

Here's an example using http. Adapt it for dio if you prefer that.

```
main() async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
      'https://25live.collegenet.com/25live/data/umd/run/availability/availabilitydata.json?etc');
  String val = response.body;
  String validJson = val.split('\n')[1];
  Map<String, dynamic> decodedJson = json.decode(validJson);
  print(decodedJson);
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing I could find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572295/what-kind-of-json-answer-starts-with

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: Wow! Have learnt something new 2day. Seeing that for the first time.