# Javascript and Playwright page.on - beginning of data is truncated

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am using page.on to capture data from a file that is being loaded in the background.  it works fine, but the beginning of the file is always truncated from the same spot and I can't figure out why.

```
const { chromium } = require("playwright");
const fs = require("fs");

async function run() {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false,
  });

  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto(
    "https://www.google.com/maps/place/Hwy.+49+Sporting+Goods/@35.4973143,-80.2115411,15z/data=!4m8!3m7!1s0x885478b921983013:0x319ffde9405d2504!8m2!3d35.497264!4d-80.202698!9m1!1b1!16s%2Fg%2F1tkkvl5r?entry=ttu",
  );

  page.on("response", async (ResponseData) => {
    if (
      ResponseData.url().indexOf(
        "https://www.google.com/maps/preview/review/listentitiesreviews?",
      ) > -1
    ) {
      console.log(ResponseData.url());
      var jsonData = await ResponseData.text();
      saveData(jsonData);
    }
  });

  await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
}

function saveData(data) {
  fs.writeFile("data.json", data, "utf8", function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("file has been saved.");
  });
}

run();
```

I have tried to set this up multiple ways, but this is as close as I have gotten to get it working.  It works, but the beginning of the data is missing for some reason.

Comment: Can you precisely define what is that "beginning of the data"?

Comment: I think you're referring to `)]}'` at the start of the JSON data. This isn't missing data, just a leader that Google adds to their JSON responses for a security reason similar to `while(1)`. See [Why does Google prepend while(1); to their JSON responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669690/why-does-google-prepend-while1-to-their-json-responses) and [What kind of json answer starts with )\]}'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6572295/what-kind-of-json-answer-starts-with?rq=3). Just strip it off with `data.replace(/^\)\]}'/, "")` and be on your way.

Comment: @ggorlen Wow.. yep.. that is it.  I had myself so convinced that part of it was being cut off that I didn't realize, it was actually just added.  Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Another thing: I would do `page.on` before `page.goto`. Otherwise, the response may be missed. Better yet, if you're blocking for one response, `page.waitForResponse` is clearer and easier to work with than `page.on("response", ` since it returns a promise so you don't have to continue writing code in a callback. `fs.writeFile` should also use the promise version rather than the legacy callback version.